# Problems installing MySQL 5.7 properly on fresh CentOS 7 install

Tags: mysql, magento, terminal, centos7, putty

I admit that I am new to back-end work in general and I seem to be stuck (for several hours) following through with completing the setting up process for Magento 2.3

I was following https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/mysql.html for my commands but to no success.

I managed to get the following installed:

- Cent OS 7 (x86_64)
- Apache 2.4.6
- PHP 7.2.14 (all the extensions installed passed the Setup Wizard readiness check)

I used these commands to install MySQL 5.7 Community Release: (from the documentation)

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm
yum -y install mysql mysql-server
yum -y install mysql-community-server
```

To check if my installation went well, when I run:

```
mysql --version
```

I received an error message saying:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/mysql: No such file or directory
```

I know that there is something I definitely am missing out completely. When I try to start the MySQL service using the command:

```
systemctl start mysqld
```

I get the resulting error message:

```
Failed to start mysqld.service: Unit not found.
```

Any suggestions will much be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: looks like you didnt' (`yum -y `) install `mysql57-community-release-el7-7` which you downloaded

Comment: so running `yum -y install mysql` doesn't work... what command do you have in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing MySQL 5.7 community release from my Cent OS, I decided to install MariaDB.

Inside the directory /etc/yum.repos.d/ I've created a file called MariaDB.repo and added this into the file:

```
# MariaDB 10.3 CentOS repository list - created 2019-01-25 05:36 UTC
# http://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.3/centos7-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

I then performed the command in my terminal window:

```
sudo yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
```

Because of this, `mysql --version` and `systemctl start mysql` works like a charm. Thanks @greenberet123 and @danblack for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it installed it as mariadb?

```
systemctl start mariadb
```

Comment: And if this doesn't show up, you can install it. Or grab a recent version from http://downloads.mariadb.org/

Comment: For some strange reason, I am having problems installing mariadb as mysql claims it has rendered it obsolete

Comment: pick one and only one. Then run it. Both should work equally as well.